# Как изменить фон ImageButton, не изменяя его размер?

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня есть LinearLayout со значением weightSum=5, для того чтобы разместить там 5 кнопок равномерно. Вот код каждого ImageButton, который я использую в нём:

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/search_60" />
```

Тогда получаю следующее: [image]

Пытаюсь изменить цвет фона одной из кнопок:

```
<ImageButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/search_60"
     android:background="@color/teal_700" />
```

Тогда  получаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как мне изменить цвет фона каждого из ImageButton так, чтобы их размеры остались прежними?

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, указав для LinearLayouta атрибут weightSum = 100, и для каждого ImageButton размер в процентах layout_weight="20" (100 / 5 = 20, для другого количества элементов n значение будет равно 100/n):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]